# Applying Child Theme to another site, which has its own URL

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, child-theme

Not an expert with Wordpress.

I have a site with a Parent Theme and I have contents of a potential site in a subdirectory. My aim is to apply the same theme to the potential site and also give it a custom URL.

To this end I have done the following:
1) Created a child Theme out of my Parent Theme
2) Created the necessary pages required for potential site inside the sub-directory following the child-theme

Any idea on how to make the potential site have its own URL?

Parent Site : www.abc.com

I can do   --> Potantial Site: www.abc/xyz.com

But I want --> Potential Site:www.xyz.com

I am also open to changing the parent-child theme approach.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This isn't how WordPress works.  Your public content (pages, posts, etc) should be served from the database, not static files.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesnt work this way. You can either have single sites like:

- abc.com
- xyz.com

but then each need its own system, database and setup (of course you can clone pages easily with plugin "Duplicator").

Or you can have a multisite installation like:

- abc.com
- xyc.abc.com

They share ONE system and one database but are more complicated than single sites on their own.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way i can point the subdomain xyz.abc.com to xyz.com? Even the content in this link https://wpengine.com/support/multisite-how-to-add-new-sites/ is not relevant to my case?

Comment: thats what i explaimes above. well depending on your provider you may use frame redirections. But you will loose any seo impact cause the sites source is in a frame